# Webdriver IO v8 - Still getting logging even though logLevel is set to silent

Tags: webdriver-io, wdio

I am using webdriver IO v8.

I have set logLevel to 'silent' in wdioconf.js.

However I am still getting reams and reams of INFO being logged to the console.

(I have also tried setting logLevels for all the packages - but that didn't make any difference either.)

I have also tried setting ChromeOptions to --silent;

Here is my wdio.conf file:

```
const testConfig = require('./config/config');
const { ReportAggregator, HtmlReporter} = require('@rpii/wdio-html-reporter');
const moment = require('moment');
const video = require('wdio-video-reporter');
let chromeOptions = {};


if(~process.argv.indexOf('--headless')) {
  chromeOptions.args = ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--start-maximized', '--window-size=1920,1080', '--silent']
}
else
{
chromeOptions.args = ['--start-maximized', '--silent'];
}

exports.config = {
  debug: true,
  
  runner: 'local',
 
  specs: [],

  exclude: [

  ],
  
  maxInstances: testConfig.maxInstance,
 
  capabilities: [
    {
      
      maxInstances: testConfig.maxInstance,
      
      browserName: testConfig.browserName,
      
    },
  ],
  
  logLevel: 'silent',
  logLevels: {
    '@babel/cli': 'silent',
    '@babel/core': 'silent',
    '@babel/preset-env': 'silent',
    '@babel/register': "^7.22.5",
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties': 'silent',
    '@wdio/cli': 'silent',
    '@wdio/local-runner': 'silent',
    '@wdio/mocha-framework': 'silent',
    '@wdio/spec-reporter': 'silent',
    'babel-eslint': 'silent',
    'chromedriver': 'silent',
    'wdio-chromedriver-service': 'silent',
    'wdio-video-reporter': 'silent',

  },
  
  bail: testConfig.bail,
  
  waitforTimeout: testConfig.waitForTimeout,
 
  connectionRetryTimeout: testConfig.connectionRetryTimeout,
  
  connectionRetryCount: testConfig.connectionRetryCount,
  
  services: ['chromedriver'],

  
  framework: 'mocha',
  
  specFileRetries: testConfig.specFileRetries,
  
  specFileRetriesDeferred: true,
  
  reporters: ['spec',
  
  ],


  port: 4444,

 
  mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 180000,
    
    bail: true,
  },
  
  onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {

    const timestamp = moment().format('DDMMYYYY_HHmm');
    let reportAggregator = new ReportAggregator({
        outputDir: './reports/html-reports/',
        filename: 'Test_Automation_Report_'+timestamp+'.html',
        reportTitle: 'Test Automation Report_'+timestamp,
        browserName : 'chrome',

    });
    reportAggregator.clean();

    global.reportAggregator = reportAggregator;
},
  
  afterTest: function (test, context, { passed }) {
        
    const path = require('path');

    if(!passed){
      const timestamp = moment().format('DDMMYYYY_HHmm');
      let filepathArray = (test.file).split('\\');
      let filename = filepathArray[filepathArray.length - 1].split('.js')[0];
      let screenshotName = filename + "_" + test.title + "_FAILED_"+timestamp;
      const filepath = path.join('reports/html-reports/screenshots/', screenshotName + '.png');
      browser.saveScreenshot(filepath);
      process.emit('test:screenshot', filepath);
    }
    
},

  
  onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
    (async () => {
        await global.reportAggregator.createReport();
    })();
},
 
};
```

So everything is set to silent but I am still getting loads of logging as shown here:

```
[0717/111551.778:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[0717/111555.425:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "MediaSDK: [11:15:55 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time).419] [Media] configure({
    "trackingServer": "dixonsrt.hb-api.omtrdc.net",
    "channel": "dixonsrtcurrysomnichannelprod",
    "appVersion": "3.0.2",
    "playerName": "generic_player",
    "ssl": true,
    "debugLogging": true
})", source:  (2)
[0717/111555.438:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "MediaSDK: [11:15:55 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time).438] [WebECResolver] AppMeasurement ready", source:  (2)
[0717/111555.440:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "MediaSDK: [11:15:55 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time).439] [WebECResolver] OptIn service not used, defaulting privacy status to {
    "ecid": "optin",
    "analytics": "optin",
    "mediaanalytics": "optin"
}", source:  (2)
[0717/111555.441:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "MediaSDK: [11:15:55 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time).439] [MediaProcessor] Configured with resolver", source:  (2)
```

These is my packages.json file:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.11.2",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.11.2",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.11.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.11.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "chromedriver": "^114.0.2",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1",
    "wdio-video-reporter": "^3.1.2"
  }
```